# ngIf with condition loses original object for let binding; with async pipe

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

Suppose I am tracking the currently logged in user like this. If the user is null, they aren't logged in. If logged in, they are either anonymous (no name) or not.

```
interface User {
  name?: string;
}

currentUser$: Observable<User>;
```

Now suppose I want to display something if the user is not anonymous, like this...

```
<div *ngIf="(this.currentUser$ | async)?.name != null; let user">
    Hello {{user.name}}
</div>
```

This does NOT work because the `user` variable gets bound to a boolean, not to the original user from the async pipe. Likewise I can't use *ngIf to find the logged in users - anonymous or not - since as soon as I run the condition `(this.currentUser$ | async) != null; let user` I no longer have access to the user object to use in the template.

I tried something like this...

```
<ng-container *ngIf="this.currentUser$ | async; let user">
    <div *ngIf="user === 'none'">Need to sign in</div>
    <div *ngIf="user !== 'none' && user.name==null">Hi stranger</div>
    <div *ngIf="user !== 'none' && user.name!=null">Hi {{user.name}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

But this doesn't work either. First, I need to convert my observable to one where `null` gets swapped with something else, like -1 or the string `none`, because I'm pretty sure otherwise the *ngIf will return false. And then the `user.name==null` part won't compile since Angular still thinks the variable is a User | 'none', not just a User. I wasn't able to figure out how to cast it to make the error go away.

I think I can do most of what I want by subscribing to the observable in my component, storing the current user details as a variable or two, and then using `{{currentUser}}` in the template. This is a bunch of extra work and I need to remember to unsubscribe. Kind of defeats the coolness of the async pipe.

What am I missing here? I'm coming from a asp.net Razor background where you can define temp variables inside the template and I guess I want to do something similar here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple things: first remove `this` from your html, that's not needed.
Secondly, you can do: `(this.currentUser$ | async) as user`

```
<div *ngIf="(this.currentUser$ | async) as user">
    <span *ngIf="user.name">Hello {{user.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Strange. I just tried this and it works. I was getting compile errors with my ng-container approach above but now it works. I realize another way to go is to define more observables in my model, like $loggedinUser which is an Observable<User | null>. I use a bunch of map, filter, etc. which I couldn't actually put into the Angular template syntax.

Comment: If you're going that route, you might as well define `loggedInUser$: Observable<User>` and filter for `user === null` in the stream, so you get rid of the potential `null` case :)

Comment: i don't think that will work because when the logged in user changes to null i want that ngif branch to not get rendered.

Comment: Although I can get my code to work I still find this ngif syntax super awkward. If you want to use an if condition, you lose the object you were testing and can't use it in the template. So to work around this I end up creating an rxjs expression in my component code that produces exactly what I need in the true case, or null in the false case. Is this awkward for anyone else? Maybe I'm not thinking about it the right way.